# VHDL: Syntax error near if

Tags: vhdl

I'm getting the following errors:
Line 15: Syntax error near "if".
Line 4: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

It's probably a very silly question, but could anyone help? :)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity arithmetic is
    port(   I1     :in    std_logic_vector(12-1 downto 0); -- Operand 1
            I2     :in    std_logic_vector(8-1 downto 0); -- Operand 2
            O      :out   std_logic_vector(12-1  downto 0); -- Output
            C      :out   std_logic;                       -- Carry Flag
            V      :out   std_logic;                       -- Overflow Flag
            VALID  :out   std_logic                        -- Flag to indicate if the solution is valid or not
);

begin

if ((unsigned(I1)-unsigned(I2)) > unsigned(I1)) and ((unsigned(I1)-unsigned(I2)) > unsigned(I2)) then
        C <= '1';
    else
        C <= '0';
    end if;

if I1(x)='1' and signed(std_logic_vector(unsigned(I1)-unsigned(I2)))>0 then --x ist das höchte Bit von I1
        V <= '1';
    else
        V <= '0';
    end if;

    if unsigned(I1) < unsigned(I2) then
        VALID <= '0';
    else
        VALID <= '1'; 
    end if;

und 

O <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(I1)-unsigned(I2));

end arithmetic;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL syntaxe error near if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435228/vhdl-syntaxe-error-near-if)

Comment: How duplicate when it's totally different code @user1155120

Comment: I have seen that question and it doesn't help me @user1155120

Comment: Try placing your if statements in processes eliminating that error. And a novel idea list all your errors. (Also get right of the dangling `und`).

Comment: How do you mean? @user1155120

Comment: You're also missing the end statement for the entity declaration and the architecture name declaration binding it to your entity in your architecture body.

Comment: Can you simply answer this question? @user1155120

Comment: There's no declaration for `x`.

Comment: There should be 'C' @user1155120

Comment: I can't interpret your last comment. There should be 'C' what?

Comment: Instead of x there should be c, like carry

Comment: `I1(x)` is an indexed name. `C` is not the index type of std_logic_vector (which is natural, a subtype of integer). `C` is type std_logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130163/discussion-between-azra-and-user1155120).

Comment: It's very difficult to answer your specific question, because there are a zillion errors in your code. Two things to get you going. (i) as user1155120 says, you have no `architecture`. (ii) `if` statements need to be inside processes. Look at some other VHDL. You will see that `if` statements appear inside `process`es inside `architecture`s.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, you need to go and look at some valid VHDL code. In the examples, replace `...` with signal/port names as appropriate for your design. You have a structure like:

```
entity arithmetic is
port(
  -- Your port list
);

begin

  if ( ... ) then
    -- Do something
  end if;

end arithmetic;
```

This is completely invalid. A correct description would look more like:

```
entity arithmetic is
port(
  -- Your port list
);

architecture Behavioral of arithmetic is
begin

  process ( ... )
  begin
    if ( ... ) then
      -- Do something
    end if;
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Hopefully the differences are quite obvious.

Comment: But what should be inside process? :/

Comment: I would start with the code that you have after `begin` in your question. My answer solves your original question. If you have now run into another problem, you need to create a new question asking about this specific problem; this is not a message board or forum. In any case, how should I know what you want your process to do when all you did was paste in some code and an error message?

Comment: I have paste code and error message, that's right and you wrote answer and here is processs(...) and I'm asking what there should be because it's easier to ask here than to open new question...

Comment: Have you tried putting your `if` statements inside the process? If you don't know what to put in the brackets after `process`, look at questions on 'sensitivity lists', for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949814/minimal-sensitivity-list-in-vhdl